# Firefox sees .xls doc as a Firefox/Chrome HTML document

Tags: java, excel, firefox, download

I'm currently running in to an issue with Firefox only where a user clicks on my link to download an excel file.  In chrome it downloads an excel file just fine, in IE I get the option to open/save the .xls file.  If I choose to open said file in IE, it opens in excel as expected.  Firefox however gives me a popup saying I've chosen to open said .xls file which is of type Firefox HTML document and that is incorrect.  It should be Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet, something along those lines.  I've set the response content type and header to be excel and have the .xls extension but Firefox insists on adding the "-htm" extension to the file name.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PaymentReportDetailSummary.xls");
```

What am I doing wrong to get this behavior in Firefox but not IE and Chrome?

Just a quick edit but this also occurring in Safari, which tacks on .html to the file.  Also, when saving the file in firefox it will save the file with the proper extension of .xls but with type Firefox HTML document.  Once the file is on the system however it is seen as an excel document.  So saving appears to work, but I want the ability to open the file with excel without having to save.

Comment: Does the file **save** correctly (regardless of the browser's reported media-type)?

Comment: In firefox if I go the save route it saves with Filename:  "filename".xls   Type: Firefox HTML Document (*.xls)